# How to analyze crash in printer driver from dump

Tags: callstack, crash-dumps, disassembly

I am trying to find the cause of an access violation using Konica Minolta PCL driver from a memory dump. I will try to provide as much info as needed. Maybe others in similar situations will benefit from this.

The software I am investegating is a combination of unmanaged windows written in Delphi 2007 hosting .net components via COM. Other crash dumps indicate possible connections with errors in setting floating point exceptions http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/535285/using-events-on-interop-assemblies-causes-system-stackoverflowexception#details, and I am trying to determine if there are any similarities.

A dump is created caused by a second chance exception: KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+36778 in C:\Windows\System32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3\KOAZ8J_O.DLL has caused an **access violation exception (0xC0000005)** when trying to read from memory location **0x1906ef0c** on thread 16.

Loading up Windbg I find this call stack:
    0:016> kL
    ChildEBP RetAddr
    WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
    253efdcc 22958881 KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x36778
    253efe1c 2294eff5 KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x36819
    253efe28 22976dde KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x2cf8d
    253efe68 22976e85 KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x54d76
    253efe90 7795f731 KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x54e1d
    253eff34 7795f632 ntdll!LdrShutdownThread+0xe6
    253eff44 75c576f5 ntdll!RtlExitUserThread+0x2a
    253eff58 774c03c0 KERNELBASE!FreeLibraryAndExitThread+0x5f
    253eff68 5e59367e kernel32!FreeLibraryAndExitThreadStub+0x10
    253eff88 774ced6c +0x23367e
    253eff94 7799377b kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
    253effd4 7799374e ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
    253effec 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

I do not have symbols for the printer drivers and by the offset on the last known function name I suspect the offending function is a completely different one.

```
0:016> r
eax=22920000 ebx=00000001 ecx=1906ef00 edx=22a01000 esi=24e42ff0 edi=229e6598
eip=229587e0 esp=253efdbc ebp=253efdcc iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00010206
KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x36778:
229587e0 3944d904        cmp     dword ptr [ecx+ebx*8+4],eax ds:0023:1906ef0c=????????


0:016> db ecx+ebx*8+4
1906ef0c  ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??-?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??  ????????????????
1906ef1c  ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??-?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??  ????????????????
1906ef2c  ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??-?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??  ????????????????
1906ef3c  ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??-?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??  ????????????????
1906ef4c  ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??-?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??  ????????????????
1906ef5c  ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??-?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??  ????????????????
1906ef6c  ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??-?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??  ????????????????
1906ef7c  ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??-?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??  ????????????????

0:016> uf 229587e0
KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x3676e:
229587d6 8b450c          mov     eax,dword ptr [ebp+0Ch]
229587d9 85c0            test    eax,eax
229587db 7418            je      KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x3678d (229587f5)

KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x36775:
229587dd 8b4f10          mov     ecx,dword ptr [edi+10h]

KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x36778:
229587e0 3944d904        cmp     dword ptr [ecx+ebx*8+4],eax
229587e4 740f            je      KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x3678d (229587f5)

KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x3677e:
229587e6 8b460c          mov     eax,dword ptr [esi+0Ch]
229587e9 833c9800        cmp     dword ptr [eax+ebx*4],0
229587ed 741d            je      KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x367a4 (2295880c)

KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x36787:
229587ef 8365fc00        and     dword ptr [ebp-4],0
229587f3 eb17            jmp     KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x367a4 (2295880c)

KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x3678d:
229587f5 8b460c          mov     eax,dword ptr [esi+0Ch]
229587f8 8b0c98          mov     ecx,dword ptr [eax+ebx*4]
229587fb 85c9            test    ecx,ecx
229587fd 7406            je      KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x3679d (22958805)

KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x36797:
229587ff 8b01            mov     eax,dword ptr [ecx]
22958801 6a01            push    1
22958803 ff10            call    dword ptr [eax]

KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x3679d:
22958805 8b460c          mov     eax,dword ptr [esi+0Ch]
22958808 83249800        and     dword ptr [eax+ebx*4],0

KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x367a4:
2295880c 43              inc     ebx
2295880d 3b5e08          cmp     ebx,dword ptr [esi+8]
22958810 7cc4            jl      KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x3676e (229587d6)

KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x367aa:
22958812 837dfc00        cmp     dword ptr [ebp-4],0
22958816 7435            je      KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x367e5 (2295884d)

KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x367b0:
22958818 8d5f1c          lea     ebx,[edi+1Ch]
2295881b 53              push    ebx
2295881c ff1544c19e22    call    dword ptr [KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0xca0dc (229ec144)]
22958822 56              push    esi
22958823 8d4f14          lea     ecx,[edi+14h]
22958826 e80bfcffff      call    KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x363ce (22958436)
2295882b 53              push    ebx
2295882c ff1548c19e22    call    dword ptr [KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0xca0e0 (229ec148)]
22958832 ff760c          push    dword ptr [esi+0Ch]
22958835 ff1530c19e22    call    dword ptr [KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0xca0c8 (229ec130)]
2295883b 8b06            mov     eax,dword ptr [esi]
2295883d 6a01            push    1
2295883f 8bce            mov     ecx,esi
22958841 ff10            call    dword ptr [eax]
22958843 6a00            push    0
22958845 ff37            push    dword ptr [edi]
22958847 ff15c8bf9e22    call    dword ptr [KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0xc9f60 (229ebfc8)]

KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x367e5:
2295884d 5f              pop     edi
2295884e 5e              pop     esi
2295884f 5b              pop     ebx
22958850 c9              leave
22958851 c20800          ret     8
```

Is anybody able to spot any obvious errors in this assembly code? Why would it adress this invalid memory location. I am also looking for guidance as how to pinpoint the error further. My goal is to look for a workaround (so this code block is not run) and to supply the author of the driver with as much info as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this assessment from Microsoft:

> The problem was related to below printer driver which has bad DllMain
>   implementations.
>
> ```
> Image path: C:\Windows\System32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3\KOAZ8J_O.DLL
> Image name: KOAZ8J_O.DLL
> Timestamp:        Mon Nov 02 15:14:30 2009 (4AEE86D6)
> CheckSum:         00000000
> ImageSize:        000DE000
> File version:     4.2.0.6
> Product version:  4.2.0.6
> File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
> File OS:          4 Unknown Win32
> File type:        2.0 Dll
> File date:        00000000.00000000
> Translations:     0000.04b0
> ProductName:      OpenAPIDrvLib Dynamic Link Library
> InternalName:     OAPIDrvLib42.dll
> OriginalFilename: OAPIDrvLib42.dll
> ProductVersion:   4.2.0.6
> FileVersion:      4.2.0.6
> FileDescription:  OpenAPI Driver Library for Ver.4.2
> LegalCopyright:   Copyright (C) 2009 Konica Minolta Business Technologies, Inc.  All rights reserved.
> ```
>
> ## ChildEBP RetAddr
>
> WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may
>   be wrong.
>
> 00 2758fdcc 26ed8881
>   KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x36778
>
> 01 2758fe1c 26eceff5
>   KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x36819
>
> 02 2758fe28 26ef6dde
>   KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x2cf8d
>
> 03 2758fe68 26ef6e85
>   KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x54d76
>
> 04 2758fe90 771af731
>   KOAZ8J_O!OAPIGetPrinterEncryptionSettingForDriver+0x54e1d
>
> 05 2758ff34 771af632 ntdll!LdrShutdownThread+0xe6
>
> 06 2758ff44 753b7695 ntdll!RtlExitUserThread+0x2a
>
> 07 2758ff58 766f0378 KERNELBASE!FreeLibraryAndExitThread+0x5f
>
> 08 2758ff68 51bb367e kernel32!FreeLibraryAndExitThreadStub+0x10
>
> 09 2758ff88 766fed6c +0x23367e
>
> 0a 2758ff94 771e377b kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
>
> 0b 2758ffd4 771e374e ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
>
> 0c 2758ffec 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
>
> The loader tried to call entry point method (mostly DllMain) for
>   cleanup operations. Such module performed complicated tasks and
>   damaged the memory. **We observed the similar issue from other cases on
>   this printer drivers.**
>
> You may try any printer driver or contact the printer driver vendor to
>   fix the problem.
>
> With the above information, you can discuss with the printer driver
>   vendor to review their code in DllMain and check for failure
>   possibilities. 
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682583(VS.85).aspx